# How to properly use PyDev with two different Python versions with scripts that are recalling other python scripts?

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

The story began with a very strange error while I was running my script from PyDev. Running the same script from outside will not encounter the same problem.

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
  File "C:\Python26\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I was able to find why this is happening: In PyDev I use two different Python versions: 3.1 that is the default installation and 2.6 as the alternative one.

My Windows Environment does not contains `PYTHONHOME`, `CLASSPATH`, `PYTHONPATH` but PyDev does add them.

Now the problem is at one stage my python script does execute another python script using os.system(`python second.py`) and the second script will fail with the above error.

Now I'm looking to find a way to prevent this issue, issue that is happening because it will run the execute the default python using the settings for the non-default one (added by PyDev).

I do not want to change the standard call (`python file.py`) but I want to be able to run my script from pydev without problem and being able to use default or alternative python environment.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that seams acceptable specially because it will not interfere with running the scripts on other systems, just to run `python -E second.py` - this will force Python to ignore PYTHON* environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding this quite right, but I think you're invoking a script from pydev that works okay, but this script executes another script which requires a different version.

While this would unfortunately be installation-specific, you could use os.system("c:\absolute\path\to\proper\version\of\python.exe second.py").

If PyDev is setting up conflicting environmental variables, you may want to look into subprocess over os.system.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

This will allow you to invoke a process with a handle, so you can optionally wait for it to terminate.  It will also allow you to pass environment variables upon execution.

Comment: First, calling python with full path is unacceptable. Second, the second script does not require a specific python version but because it does run the default pyhton interpretor with another python ENV settings it will just fail (python will fail). I already found a solution, to allways call this python script with -E, meaning it will ignore PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your call should be:

import sys

os.system(sys.executable+ ' second.py')

So that you guarantee you're using the same interpreter you're currently running and not launching the other one (or did you really mean to use the other interpreter?)